# pkgutil get_data: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I've written a test in which I fetch a local resource file like so:

```
from pkgutil import get_data

@fixture(scope='session')
def ref_o_full():
    return pd.read_csv(StringIO(get_data('test_data', 'ref_o.csv').decode()))
```

When I run my test I get the following exception:

```
test setup failed
@fixture(scope='session')
    def ref_o_full():
>       return pd.read_csv(StringIO(get_data('test_data', 'ref_o.csv').decode('utf8')))
E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

However, if I were to run the test in debug mode, this exception doesn't occur. It feels to me like some sort of a race condition?

I have switched to using the following which works each time:

```
from pkg_resources import resource_filename
from os.path import join as join_path

@fixture(scope='session')
def ref_o_full():
    dir = resource_filename(__name__, 'test_data')
    return pd.read_csv(join_path(dir, 'ref_o.csv'))
```

Comment: you need to check the return of `StringIO(get_data('test_data', 'ref_o.csv')` mostly probley it is nothing

Comment: Yep. As @temmo says, that value is `None`, and you can't `decode` that. If that's a valid value, then I suggest you get that value first, then return either the `decode` or just `None` accordingly.

Comment: This misses the point of the question completely. I understand that `get_date()` has returned a `None` - this is evident from the error message. I also know how to handle a method that can possibly return a `None` which is a valid case. However, considering the file `ref_o.csv` exists in the package `test_data` then `get_data()` should not return `None`. Furthermore, the test always passes when run in the debugger and never in `run` mode which is inconsistent - this means `get_data()` returns different values. Using the alternative code provided always passes.

Comment: @s5s according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html) `if the package cannot be located or loaded, or it uses a loader which does not support get_data, then None is returned. In particular, the loader for namespace packages does not support get_data.`

Comment: @s5s, have you resolved this problem? I'm seeing similar problem: codes works fine in debug mode, but after building the code to .par file, pkgutil.get_data returns None.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue, just make sure that the _*init_*.py file is present in the "test_data" directory. This will help the method to locate the package.